# Mysql find out a distribution

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query to find out a distribution.
My table has two columns: id, zone_id
I want the result to show how many ids have been in one zone, two zones, three zones etc. (there are 13 zones in total).

An id can be repeated, being a row for example id = 1 and zone_id = 1 and id = 1 and zone_id = 2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by using `GROUP BY` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with two aggregations, one to compute the number of zones for each `id`, and a second one to tally the zone counts themselves:

```
SELECT
    zone_cnt, COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT zone_id) AS zone_cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
) t
GROUP BY zone_cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using GROUP BY, your select should look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as [Distribution]
FROM your_table
GROUP BY zone_id
```